# Using R radian only on my own machine, not on remote server with vscode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I have installed radian and am using it perfectly on my own machine. However, when I try to ssh into another terminal and run R, it won't run, as it can't find radian in the r.path given.

I understand that the directory in my own computer will not lead anywhere in the remote machine. However, how do people use radian and SSH at all?

Side note, the remote machine does not have radian and I don't have authorization to install it, so ideally I'd like a solution that allows me to use radian on my home computer and vanilla R on the remote.

[image]

[image]

I tried creating the workspace and still the user settings seem to override it

Answer (score 0):

Found it - the settings on the GUI for some reason don't override User.

There's a settings.json file for the ssh in which I could add the following lines

```
{
    "r.rterm.linux": ""
    "r.rpath.linux": ""
}
```

now radian works like a charm on my home computer and I can run R on my remote!

Comment: what is the location of this `settings.json`

Comment: Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON) command in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)

Comment: If you use the GUI you have to look for which settings you change: User/Global - Workspace - Folder